# AWS SNS webservice subscription - express issue, sinatra example

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-sns

I'm simply trying to build an auto-subscription API which POSTs back the token. I can do this very easily in Sinatra (render the POSTed JSON from AWS) -- seem to be having a hard time in Express; I'm sure it's just something stupid I'm missing, though I've tried 1000X combinations.

Here is the Sinatra webserver:

```
# application.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

set :port, 8081

post '/webservice/cloudwatch' do
  content_type :json
  puts "Body: " + request.body.read
end
```

Which logs:

```
- -> /webservice/cloudwatch
Body: {
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "OMIT",
  "Token" : "OMIT",
  "TopicArn" : "OMIT",
  "Message" : "OMIT",
  "SubscribeURL" : "OMIT",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-02-28T21:28:02.082Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "OMIT",
  "SigningCertURL" : "OMIT"
}
```

Here is the Express webserver:

```
var express, app, stache;
express = require("express"), app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.set("view options", {
    layout: false
  });
  app.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
  }));
});
app.post("/webservice/cloudwatch", function (request, response) {
  request.accepts('application/json');
  console.log("post body: " + JSON.stringify(request.params));
  console.log("post body: " + JSON.stringify(request.body.read));
});  
app.listen(8081);
```

Which logs:

```
post body: []
post body: undefined
```

Please help!

Comment: instead of doing a `console.log` on `request.body.read` try doing a `console.dir` on `request.body` and see what attributes it contains.

Comment: console.dir(request.body);  This logs {}

Comment: console.dir(request.body.read); This logs undefined

Comment: Okay. Take a look at the [Node Docs on ServerRequest objects](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#http.ServerRequest). I'm not familiar with Sinatra, but maybe you are looking for `request.headers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which request are you using to test your webservice? Doing:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Type":"SubscriptionConfirmation","MessageId":"OMIT","Token":"OMIT","TopicArn":"OMIT","Message":"OMIT","SubscribeURL":"OMIT","Timestamp":"2012-02-28T21:28:02.082Z","SignatureVersion":"1","Signature":"OMIT","SigningCertURL":"OMIT"}' http://localhost:8081/webservice/cloudwatch
```

(notice the content-type set to application/json) and changing your `console.log` to `console.log(request.body);` should give you the expected results. The bodyParser method needs to know the content-type to correctly populate request.body.

Answer (score 2):

When amazon sends the http post request to your endpoint, it doesn't specify a content type.  This is a known issue for them, based on their responses.

In the meantime there is a very hacky workaround I've been testing.  I modified the bodyParser.js file in the express plugin.  Specifically, I added an if check to the mime function such that I can force it to pretend the content-type is `application/json` as necessary.

Here is the modified mime function:

```
function mime(req) {
    if(req.headers['x-amz-sns-message-type'] == 'SubscriptionConfirmation' && !req.headers.hasOwnProperty['content-type']) {
        req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    var str = req.headers['content-type'] || '';
    return str.split(';')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your express server (make sure bodyParser comes after rawbody). Try logging request.rawbody

```
var rawbody = function(req, res, next) {
    var data = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
    req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
};

app.use(rawbody);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Thanks to: [Expressjs raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920208/expressjs-raw-body/13565786#13565786)