# Posting a file from one node service to a node webservice

Tags: node.js

I have the following client service:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = "c:\\log.txt";
var url = "http://localhost:8080/upload";

fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(request.post(url));
```

Here is the code on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');
app.listen(8080);


app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

I want to eventually save the files received on the server. Right now when I run the service, then the client, the server logs an empty array - {} instead of the files uploaded.

How do I solve this?

Update:
The server code works because I successfully tested it using Fiddler.

Comment: Your data will not be posted as `files`, but as raw body, read there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644836/get-rawbody-in-express as an example middleware to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proper file uploads, you need to do a bit more work in your client:

```
var r = request.post(url);
var form = r.form();
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(file));
```

(mostly taken from [here](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms))

Answer (score 0):

`express.bodyParser()` works for `multipart/form-data` encoded bodies. You are just sending file content as a body, so you need to pipe data to writeable stream or bufferize it.