# How to validate a webhook signature in odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am looking for solution which is exactly described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486389/how-to-validate-a-webhook-signature-using-python-and-openssl)
However I am not sure what should I pass to the second parameter ie request_body
as I am unable to find body in request object of odoo.

```
digester = hmac.new(secret, request_body, hashlib.sha256)
```

I have tried to pass

"**request**" which throw error "must be convertible to a buffer, not LocalProxy".

"**request.httprequest**" which throw error "must be convertible to a buffer, not Request".

"**request.jsonrequest**" which throw error "must be convertible to a buffer, not dict".

"**str(request.jsonrequest)**" which process this but give invalid signature.

Any input other than above will be very helpful.
If you are not sure but you may have possible solution. Give a try, I will test and let you know.
I am using odoo v10

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an issue with `type='json'` controller endpoints, because when the `Content-Type` of the request is `application/json` the request stream is parsed and consumed by Odoo and is no longer available within the controller method.

This issue has already been reported on Odoo [issue tracker](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/7766), there appears to be no 100% solution yet, however.