# Issues Matching WooCommerce WebHook signature on Node.JS

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to a validate the webhook transaction from WooCommerce on my Node.js website. However I cannot get the 2 strings to match.

I can see that the php signature is generated with the following code, and the source can be viewed here [WooCommerce Source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-webhook.php#L303-L317).

```
base64_encode( hash_hmac( $hash_algo, $payload, $this->get_secret(), true ) ));
```

I have noticed that if i turn off `true` on the `hash_hmac`, I can then get the 2 systems to create a match, however I would rather not edit the core of WooCommerce so I am wondering if there is something I am missing here?

For my Example I did edit the core and forced the payload to be the following, just so i could easily try and match the 2 systems

```
payload = '{"id":1,"etc":2,"host":"http:/\/localhost\/view-order\/8"}'
secret = 'welcome'
```

My code in Node.Js is the following.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');    

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
hmac.setEncoding('binary');
hmac.write(payload);
hmac.end();
hash = hmac.read();

result = base64.encode(hash);

console.log(result);
```

**If I** remove the url from the "host" JSON then it does work, is it something to do with the way it has been escaped?
I think it may be an issue with the way PHP and node do the SHA256 hashing. I really can't workout exactly how to solve this.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: did you eventually figure this out? I'm still working on getting an order update webhook to fire properly, and after that I suspect I'll run into this problem.

Comment: I never resolved the miss matching crypto properly, I ended up modifying the way woo commerce creates the hash in it's core, not the best solution as I need to update this every time woo updates... If you have manage to get the 2 to be synced natively, i'd love to see the code!

Comment: @fortuneRice Did you have any luck?

Comment: I had to put that project on hold so I'm not at that stage yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into a similar issue as you, using the code suggested here:
[SHA256 webhook signature from WooCommerce never verifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122736/sha256-webhook-signature-from-woocommerce-never-verifies)

```
var processWebHookSignature = function (secret, body, signature) {
  signatureComputed = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', secret)
  .update(new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body), 'utf8'))
  .digest('base64');

  return ( signatureComputed === signature ) ? true : false;
}
```

(Where body comes from req.body).

This only started working for me when I changed the way I obtain the raw body. I got it using the bodyParser middleware:
`app.use(bodyParser.json({verify:function(req,res,buf){req.rawBody=buf}}))`
(As explained in: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/83#issuecomment-80784100)

So now instead of using 
`new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body), 'utf8')` I just use `req.rawBody`
I hope this solves your problems too.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Extending @genau's answer:

**You may ask, why is the issue happening!?** 

Almost all of us add the below code in our express app, which manipulates the actual `req.body`, causing issues in authenticating hash signatures.

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

**How to handle this issue?**
Add original `req.body` to a new field (for eg: `req.rawBody`), and use this field instead of `req.body` while verifying the signature.

```js
// This code will copy the req.body data to req.rawBody
app.use(
  express.json({
    verify: function (req, res, buf) {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
  })
);
```

Later, you can verify the signature as shown below:

```js
function requestHandler (req, res) {
    const incomingSignature = req.headers["x-wc-webhook-signature"]; // modify this accordingly
    const payload = req.rawBody; // Buffer, already, no need to stringify.

    const calculatedSignature = crypto
        .createHmac("sha256", "your-secret-key")
        .update(payload)
        .digest("base64");

    const isValid = calculatedSignature === incomingSignature;
  
    // ...
}
```

Thanks!