# Proper way to verify the signature coming from WooCommerce webhooks

Tags: node.js, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am running into a strange issue when I try to verify the signature coming from the WooCommerce webhooks. Here is the part I use to create the signature:

```
verified = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', secret).update(new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body), 'utf8')).digest('base64');
```

It works for every webhook with a `removed` topic, and the request body is equal to something like this:

```
{"id":360}
```

Unfortunately, for every webhook with an `updated` or `created` topic, my signatures aren't the same. The request body is also more complex.

```
 {"product":{"title":"Test","id":392,"created_at":"2017-02-11T21:40:37Z","updated_at":"2017-02-11T21:40:37Z","type":"simple","status":"publish","downloadable":false,"virtual":false,"permalink":"http://cedrus.ma/chezalfred/livraison/non classu00e9/test/","sku":"","price":"","regular_price":"","sale_price":null,"price_html":"","taxable":true,"tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","managing_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"purchaseable":false,"featured":false,"visible":true,"catalog_visibility":"visible","on_sale":false,"product_url":"","button_text":"","weight":null,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":"","unit":"cm"},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":null,"description":"","short_description":"","reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"categories":[],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":0,"created_at":"2017-02-11T21:40:40Z","updated_at":"2017-02-11T21:40:40Z","src":"http://cedrus.ma/chezalfred/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png","title":"Etiquette","alt":"Etiquette","position":0}],"featured_src":"","attributes":[],"downloads":[],"download_limit":0,"download_expiry":0,"download_type":"","purchase_note":"","total_sales":0,"variations":[],"parent":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0}}
```

I think there is something wrong that happens with JSON.stringify() when the request body is more complex.

What is the proper way to verify the signature coming from WooCommerce webhooks?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue as you, using the same code (It apparently works for some people, as mentioned here: [SHA256 webhook signature from WooCommerce never verifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122736/sha256-webhook-signature-from-woocommerce-never-verifies))

What finally worked for me was getting the raw body value in a different way, using the bodyParser middleware:
`app.use(bodyParser.json({verify:function(req,res,buf){req.rawBody=buf}}))`
(As explained in: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/83#issuecomment-80784100)

So now instead of using 
`new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body), 'utf8')` I just use `req.rawBody`
I hope this solves your problems too.