# ASP.NET Core : Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET core server, `AllowSynchronousIO` is set to `false`

```
        new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = false;
        })
```

In the action, it outputs a JsonResult

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> SanityCheck()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = await GetDic();

        return this.Json(dic);
    }
```

And it ends with an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are
> disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.

Can't I return a JsonResult with `AllowSynchronousIO=false` ?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You might have the following problem: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8302

And you can find more info here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7644

A workaround until the issue is being solved is to allow Synchronous IO. Put this in Startup.cs for either Kestrel or IIS:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // If using Kestrel:
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });

    // If using IIS:
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm hosting an ASP.NET core app in a Windows service. What would I do to allow synchronous IO?

Comment: Adding the Kestrel configuration worked. I assume it's using Kestrel in my case, that makes sense.

Comment: Is there a way to send back the JsonResult asynchronously? I think that would be a better solution than allowing synchronous operations on the server.

Comment: Do you or anybody else know the F# syntax for this?

Comment: If the above code still doesn't help to solve the issue - please try updating related nuget's to the latest version. This helped for me.

Answer (score 37):

I managed to find my own unique version of this problem with the following middleware (.NET 6.0):

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("Done!");
        return;
    }
}
```

I spent a long time staring at this until I realised what the stack trace was telling me:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>
> at System.IO.Stream.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>
> **at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()**

The important line here was the `System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()`: this is causing the resulting flush and lower-level write to be called synchronously.

Fortunately, `StreamWriter` implements `IAsyncDisposable` so it's easy to solve it by adding `await` before `using`:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    await using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("Done!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone not waste as much time as I did.

Comment: Yep - sure saved some time here! Thank you :)

Comment: The error message is so dumb. In my code, it throw an error at `await writer.WriteAsync` call and the error tells me `Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.`. Thankfully I found this answer.

Comment: Good for you. I have the exact same problem with ZipArchive streams, that unfortunately do not implement `iAsynDisposable` :(
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1560

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what was happening to me. I was staring in disbelief since I was using `WriteLineAsync` already! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 34):

When the exception is thrown in code you cannot control, and you have no other choice than to enable `AllowSynchronousIO`, it is best to enable it for specific requests, instead of globally.

In the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644) announcing this feature, the following workaround is suggested:

```cs
var syncIOFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
if (syncIOFeature != null)
{
    syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
}
```

You can create a simple middleware function to apply this to specific requests:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/some-endpoint-that-needs-sync-io"))
    {
        var syncIoFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
        if (syncIoFeature != null)
        {
            syncIoFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        }
    }

    await next();
})
```

Comment: Voting for this answer, as it enables only for certain requests and keep the recommended setting for the rest. It also extends the source issue description by full sample code.

Comment: CAUTION:  You have to be very careful when updating the context features to avoid any race conditions causing the issue of https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42040, basically unless you are single threaded (i.e. always awaiting any async tasks) you should prefer to synchronize all access to the request by using a lock statement etc.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Mark Lagendijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665825/mark-lagendijk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67632199/1401886), i applied that logic on a declarative way with an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowSynchronousIOAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public AllowSynchronousIOAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var syncIOFeature = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
        if (syncIOFeature != null)
        {
            syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Just use it on an action method or an entire controller to enable it:

```
[AllowSynchronousIO]
public IActionResult DownloadSynchronous()
{
    return Something();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue with my unit tests.  I had to update my TestServer to AlloSynchronousIO

```
Server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
Server.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
```

Answer (score 6):

In the configure service add below code. It worked for me

```
 services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });

            // If using IIS:
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when writing `ZipArchive` into `Response.Body` which throws the exact same error, because `ZipArchive` does not implement `IAsynDisposable`

```
using (var z = new ZipArchive(Response.Body, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    //fill the zip archive
} //exception thrown here
```

#### The workaorund is to write into `Response.BodyWriter.AsStream()`

```
using (var z = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    //fill the zip archive
}
```

Comment: This helped me with `CsvHelper` as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your requirements are or what `GetDic()` does, but code like the following should absolutely work given `GetDic()` doesn't do any synchronous IO:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SanityCheck()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = await GetDic();

    return this.Ok(dic);
}
```

And if you still want to serialise `dic` to JSON, the following code should do:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SanityCheck()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = await GetDic();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);

    return this.Ok(json);
}
```

Note that this last piece of code returns the result as `text/plain` instead of `application/json`.

Also, I tested this under ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

this code work for me, make async read:

```
public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    string content = "";
    var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
    try
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();
        request.Body.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8,true,1024,true))
        {
            content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody else is showing how to allow synchronous IO.
In my case, the problem was that my custom stream classes were not implementing `DisposeAsync` and `FlushAsync` correctly.
Fixing that made the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I upgraded an Azure Function Project from .NETCoreApp v3.1 to .NET6.0, and getting this error.

So what I did was change HttpMessage for IActionResult.

My code was like this:

```
[FunctionName("SayHello")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "SayHello")]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    string name =  await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}
```

And, now:

```
[FunctionName("SayHello")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "SayHello")]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    string name =  await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
    return new OkObjectResult("Hello " + name);
}
```