# .NET 8 : deserializing of HttpContent Int payload returns null

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-8.0, jsonserializer

New to .NET 8.0. I am posting to a Rest API and expect the returned payload to be an `id` number. I am attempting to deserialize an `HttpContent` stream into a class called `Result<T>` where T is a payload (see code below). The int payload always deserializes as null. I have created a dictionary version of the same object to show the int Payload is coming back properly. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Viewing both Payloads at runtime after serialization]

Function to post to the API and return result:

```
...
try
{
    var obj = new T();
    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    byte[] bytes = null;
    bytes = readTask.Result;
    obj = readTask !=null ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bytes) : null;
    var objAsDict = readTask !=null ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(bytes) : null;
    return obj;
}
...
```

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Success => !ErrorDetails.Any();
    public bool Failure => !Success;
    public List<ErrorDetail> ErrorDetails { get; private set; } = new List<ErrorDetail>();
    public List<string> ExceptionDetails { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Warnings { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    ...
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Payload { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I changed to reading the `result.Content` using `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` to test incoming payload as a dictionary. I changed my payload object to be an explicit int instead of T. I verified my `Result` and `Result<T>` accessors are correct. Nothing changed with each test.

Comment: As you're saying this is JSON, please show us an example JSON DTO from-the-wire.

Comment: You're using `Task` incorrectly: you must not call `task.Result` without first `await`ing it - otherwise you'll either deadlock - or [ASP.NET Core will tell you off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735133/asp-net-core-synchronous-operations-are-disallowed-call-writeasync-or-set-all).

Comment: ...why aren't you using ASP.NET Core's built-in model-binding functionality? You shouldn't normally ever need to use a deserialization library yourself...

Comment: If you do `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, does it return the JSON that matches the model you have?

Comment: @Dai Here is whats coming from the wire:

{"payload":61,"success":true,"failure":false,"errorDetails":[],"exceptionDetails":[],"warnings":[]}

Also I added the await.

Comment: @juunas Yes it does. Here:
{"payload":61,"success":true,"failure":false,"errorDetails":[],"exceptionDetails":[],"warnings":[]}

Comment: could you try setting `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `true`. You might need to use reflection or other means to explicitly tell the serializer what `T` is, especially if `T` could be an `int` or other value type.use `byte[] bytes = await readTask;` instead of `readTask.Result;`. could you share the code with await you have tried