# Error 400 (Bad Request) from Visual Studio 2015 Ripple

Tags: wcf, cordova, ripple

I am trying to access as WCF service from Visual Studio's 2015 Android Ripple Emulator but I'm getting an error 400: Bad Request. I modified the proxy.js found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\proxy.js

from:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'}));
```

but this did not solve the problem and is trying to access the WCF service as follows - http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rur…http%3A//example.com/Service.svc/GoodToGo%3Fmessage%3DOK

Has anyone managed to solve the issue (I did not manage after going through this thread - [Expressjs raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920208/expressjs-raw-body))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this error by disabling the web security.

1. Close all Chrome instances.
2. Open Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` argument.
3. Run the app by Ripple.
4. On the right panel of the page, click `setting -> cross domain proxy`, and set it to `disable`.
5. Refresh the app and run.

Comment: Thanks. So basically what I'm doing is I'm disabling all web security on Chrome (temporarily) to get around the problem.