# Getting 'The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format' when hybrid app connect to SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, signalr

I have done a lot of research online but can't find the solution. I have created a SignalR hub on the WebAPI backend and enabled the CORS feature.

I also have a client (Ionic) app try to connect to the SignalR hub for real-time chat. The problem is that when the Hybrid app tries to connect to the SignalR hub, I am getting

> The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.

I am getting `OnDisconnected` Event on the SignalR Hub BUT not the `OnConnected` Event!

This is my client code (ionic):

- localhost:64965/signalr is my SignalR hub
- SignalR Proxy also generated on localhost:64965/signalr/hubs

```js
var signalr_chatHub = $.connection.ChatHub;

signalr_chatHub.client.welcomeMessage = function (message) {
      console.log('WelcomeMessage', message);
};

$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:64965/signalr";
$.connection.hub.logging = true;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      console.log('signal connection connected');
}).fail(function (err) {
      console.log('Could not Connect!', err);
});
```

Chrome Console Errors:

[image: chrome console errors]

```cs
public class ChatHub : Hub<IChat>
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    public void WelcomeMessage()
    {
        Clients.All.NewMessage("Welcome");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error, but still not able find proper solution.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762303/error-400-bad-request-from-visual-studio-2015-ripple

Answer (score 0):

Cordova by any chance?

The reason this happens is because ripple creates a "cross domain proxy", this grabs all generated uri's from signalR and incorrectly encodes parts.

fix is: set ripple, settings => cross domain proxy to "disabled"

below is an example of a proxied request, note the http%3a8080...:

http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/signalr/start%3Ftransport%3DwebSockets%26clientProtocol%3D1.5%26connectionToken%3DAQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%252FCl%252BsBAAAA7b4HHv1ZFkq9Xe5qXnUfYwAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACU%252BVDaQ6ENxgEPcm8Tjmr39SnBszhmBjUib5UoPoXKxgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADoJqphu6%252BQ48B4d6J6QxbK%252FqKemI3%252FJiDfnCJRKtDMuDAAAACd3g9DsBiiG3CFNcDf0maC534kevbjNczDyFFCNSHeZB%252BNfX%252FkAXX74kYLEEUeqYNAAAAAvtEsnhNjbThhsJd0L7EN%252FNsTuK7M3ijALDGtP161hI2iobBj7%252FcItg%252FQmADPDOWlKIl7SgsRXU1dLXoOumpv%252Fw%253D%253D%26connectionData%3D%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522myhub%2522%257D%255D%26_%3D1494802918927

This bug took 5 hours of my life, damn them tiny hippos.