# How to receive text on POST with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I need to receive simple text on my POST route:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const functions = require('../../utils/functions');

let router = express.Router();

router.post('/ses', function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.body)

});

module.exports = router;
```

It returns `{}`

I found some people using body parse and I tried to use like this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

router.use(bodyParser.json());

// and tried it too. Not together, of course
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

It didn't work. I'm not a NodeJS pro. How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [bodyParser.text()](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions) is what you are looking for.

See [Expressjs raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920208/expressjs-raw-body)